# Programming an html email with images

Tags: html, email, html-email

Is there any way to display image `ALT` text larger for an HTML E-Mail in case the user doesn't display image in his email? The alt text is too small...

Comment: could you maybe possibly add more to your question??

Comment: Seems a reasonable question to me :/

Comment: I Agree with Sam Warren here. This is a legitimate and reasonable question. It should be reopened.

Comment: You should read this article: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/dreamweaver/articles/html_emails.html - Has great information on creating HTML E-Mails and includes info on ALT Text being displayed larger. (Same solution as Sam Warren recommended)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is yes. But it doesnt work on all email clients. Looking at you Outlook 2007 -.-

What you need to do is style the image using normal inline css, such as below.

```
<img src="imageaddress.jpg" alt="image" style="font-size:24px; color:#fff" />
```

Also if it helps a couple of pointers for images in email.

1. Always use display:block in the style tag for every image (corrects gmail spacing bug below image)
2. Always use border=0 in the image tag on any link that will be clickable to stop a blue border appearing.

I hope this helps!

Comment: thank you! it showed in my client. i hope it will show in others!

Answer (score 2):

You can apply the CSS `font-size` property to both the `img` element and its parent node. I wouldn't expect many email clients to pay much attention to it though.

Answer (score 1):

You should try to put a style="font-size:19px;" on the  tag.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change the size of the alternative text of an image.